# In Django how to create a template tag that renders a login form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm wondering if the following is possible and need an example.

I would like to create a template tag that renders a login form. Can this be done and guidance, please.

The reason behind this is that I have a login form that needs to be on every page of my site. I have decided this would be better as a tag which I can just include. I want to use the form from my forms.py and not hardcode it.

i.e.

```
from django import template
from accounts.forms import AuthenticationForm

register = template.Library()


 def authentication_form():
    render this form == AuthenticationForm() ?????
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) which is a tag that renders a template.

First define your template for example in a file called `_tag_auth_form.html`:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ action }}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then your template tag simply renders the above template with the appropriate context variables:

```
from django import template
from accounts.forms import AuthenticationForm

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('_tag_auth_form.html')
def authentication_form():
    return {'form': AuthenticationForm(), 'action': '/some/url'}
```